# Last non empty cell in another workbook, indirect Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup, excel-indirect

I am trying to find the last non-empty cell in another Excel(xls/csv) workbook (not worksheet), using the indirect statement (i.e. I have the name of the workbook written in one of the cells).

I have been trying to adjust the generic LOOKUP formula `LOOKUP(2,1/A:A<>""),A:A)`, in adjusted form

`=(LOOKUP(2,1/INDIRECT("'"&Settings!$F$4&"'!A:A")<>""),INDIRECT("'"&Settings!$F$4&"'!A:A"))`

but it does not work. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: what exactly does cell `Settings!$F$4` contain? where exactly is the data to lookup and how is it laid out?  can you get the lookup working without the values hardcoded? If so, what do that formula look like?

Comment: If F4 contains the workbook name, you're missing part of the equation. You need to also provide the *worksheet* name.

Comment: `Indirect` does not work on closed workbooks

Comment: Perhaps `Settings` is the name of the worksheet where `A:A` is located, not where `F4` is located, like it's currently coded.  All speculation without knowing the other half of the story....